# It is possible to make a "Gif Viewer" with "Google Chrome" using batch? How to do "File Searcher" that open a file with another program?

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file, gif

*Sorry My Bad english! Im portuguese!*

**I was wondering if it is possible to make a "Gif Viewer" with "Google Chrome" using the batch.** What I wanted to make is that "Google chrome" open up the gifs by a ""simple click"", because I'm in the Graphic Design course, and at our school, the pc's have admin rights, so we can't change the gifs default settings, to be opened by "Google Chrome". We want to open gifs by "Chrome" because it is fast animated gifs displayer , and it's good to preview the websites that we do in html.
Another reason is because I'm enjoying learn more about batch ...

**My problem is:
   How can I make a "File Searcher" which find GIF1, 2 or 3, and open it with google    chrome (I need to do this to avoid having to be changing the directory of gifs and "google chrome", whenever I change the folder, or copy the program to my classmates)...**

*Here is my full Batch* (A little *Dinamic*):

```
ECHO OFF
CLS
TITLE ***Gif Viewer\**Hubert Kenobi**/GoogleChromePortable***
:S
color 12
color 0B
color 12
color 23
color 45
color 62
color 89
color 91
color 37
color 12
color 43
color 51
color 15
color 42
color 2
color 3
color 0A
:MENU
ECHO .
ECHO  \   
ECHO   HK 
ECHO     .......................................................
ECHO   ...                                                     ...
ECHO  ..                                                         ..
ECHO .     *--Gifs Viewer \By Hubert Kenobi/ Google Chrome--*      .    ===
ECHO  ..                                                         ..
ECHO   ...                                                     ......
ECHO     .......................................................    ...
ECHO    ..                   Y or y - Confirm                  ..     ..           
ECHO   .                   N or n - Reject/Next                  .      .  ===   ===
ECHO    ..                    E or e - Exit                    ..     ..            
ECHO     .......................................................    ...
ECHO   ...                                                     ......
ECHO  ..  To open a gif, put the gif in the folder where is the  ..
ECHO .     "Gif Viewer" with the name of Gif1, or Gif2 Gif3...     .    ===
ECHO  ..   PRESS "Y" or "N" to select your task or "E" to EXIT   ..
ECHO   ...                                                     ...
ECHO     .......................................................
ECHO   HK                                                           Hubert Kenobi
ECHO  /                                                            My spaceship!!!
ECHO .     
ECHO Do you want to see/watch gif1 ?
ECHO.

SET /P M=Type Y, N, or E, then press ENTER: 
IF %M%==Y GOTO Y
IF %M%==N GOTO N
IF %M%==E GOTO EOF
IF %M%==y GOTO Y
IF %M%==n GOTO N
IF %M%==e GOTO EOF
:Y
## I want to make a searcher that run the gif and open it with chrome!! HELP ME!!! ##
ECHO This will take few seconds...
start GoogleChromePortable.exe "L:\Informatic\GoogleChromePortable-GifViewer\Gif1.gif"
GOTO S
:N 
ECHO Do you want to see/watch gif2 ?
ECHO.

SET /P M=Type Y, N, or E, then press ENTER: 
IF %M%==Y GOTO Y2
IF %M%==N GOTO N2
IF %M%==E GOTO EOF
IF %M%==y GOTO Y2
IF %M%==n GOTO N2
IF %M%==e GOTO EOF

:Y2

## I tried this way, but it didn't work and exit automatically! ##

pushd L:\Site HTML onlive-ac
FOR /F "delims=" %F IN ('dir /S /b Gif1.gif) DO SET ExePath="%F"
%ExePath%
Goto S

:N2
ECHO Do you want to see/watch gif3 ?
ECHO.

SET /P M=Type Y, N, or E, then press ENTER: 
IF %M%==Y GOTO Y3
IF %M%==N GOTO N3
IF %M%==E GOTO EOF
IF %M%==y GOTO Y3
IF %M%==n GOTO N3
IF %M%==e GOTO EOF

:Y3
## I tried this way, but it didn't work! This opens the Gifs independently ##
## with the default program (Quick Time Player "slow program") and then ##
## opens the Chrome in the Home page. ##
SETLOCAL 

FOR /L %%a IN (2,1,3) DO (
    FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%b IN ('WMIC LogicalDisk Where "DriveType=%%a" Get DeviceID /Format:List') DO (
        FOR /F "tokens=*" %%c IN ('DIR %%b\GoogleChromePortable.exe "Gif3.gif" /b /s') DO (
            CALL "%%c"
        )
    )
)

EXIT /B
N3:
GOTO MENU
```

*Here is my summary Batch:*

**1. I want to make a searcher that run the gif and open it with chrome!!!!! This works, but doesn't the function that I want it to do!t HELP ME!!!**

```
:Y
ECHO This will take few seconds...
start GoogleChromePortable.exe "L:\Informatic\GoogleChromePortable-GifViewer\Gif1.gif"
GOTO S
```

**2. I tried this way, but it didn't work and exit automatically!**

```
:Y2
pushd L:\Site HTML onlive-ac
FOR /F "delims=" %F IN ('dir /S /b Gif1.gif) DO SET ExePath="%F"
%ExePath%
Goto S
```

**3. I tried this way, but it didn't work! This opens the Gifs independently
with the default program (Quick Time Player "slow program") and then
opens the Chrome in the Home page.**

```
SETLOCAL 
    :Y3 
    FOR /L %%a IN (2,1,3) DO (
        FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%b IN ('WMIC LogicalDisk Where "DriveType=%%a" Get DeviceID /Format:List') DO (
            FOR /F "tokens=*" %%c IN ('DIR %%b\GoogleChromePortable.exe "Gif3.gif" /b /s') DO (
                CALL "%%c"
            )
        )
    )

    EXIT /B
```

Please Help me!!!
**I did a PrintScreen to see the directorys:**
http://s5.postimage.org/h2emaxvfb/Background_Directoryies.png

**One possible solution** is creating a second batch program that changes the directories (copy or move), thus modifying the 1st batch. Is it possible? Batchs that modify other batchs? *Thanks for help!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a file chooser that you can use.  Or you can just look at various parts, like how I launch chrome to show a file.  Or how I search for all images in subdirectories, or whatever.  I wanted to show how to do it without forcing the user to rename their .gif files.

You need to configure these variables at the top of the script:

```
REM The location of the viewer to launch.
set VIEWER=C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

REM The root directory to look for files.  %~dp0 means the same directory as
REM this script, including a trailing \.
set FILES=%~dp0

REM The type of files to show.
set FILE_FILTER=^*.gif ^*.jpg ^*.png

REM When '/s', then include subdirectories below %FILES% in the search.  Leave
REM blank to restrict the search to %FILES% only.
set RECURSE=/s
```

When you launch the chooser, you get a menu that looks like this:

```
  images\buffalo.gif
  images\bull7.gif
> images\cow13.gif
  images\cow14.gif
  more images\dino 10.gif
  more images\dino19.gif
Up[W]  Down[S]  Select[E]  Quit[Q]
```

Right now, *cow13.gif* is selected.  Press **W** or **S** to change the selection up or down, respectively.  Press **E** to launch chrome to show the selected file.  **Q** quits.

Here's the full thing.  It uses `choice`, which is not always installed with Windows.  It's on my Windows 7 box, so I used it.

```
@echo off

REM The location of the viewer to launch.
set VIEWER=C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

REM The root directory to look for files.  %~dp0 means the same directory as
REM this script, including a trailing \.
set FILES=%~dp0

REM The type of files to show.
set FILE_FILTER=^*.gif ^*.jpg ^*.png

REM When '/s', then include subdirectories below %FILES% in the search.  Leave
REM blank to restrict the search to %FILES% only.
set RECURSE=/s

REM ----------------------------
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cls
call :show_splash_screen
call :pause_sec 2

set SELECTED_INDEX=0
set SELECTED=

:show_files
if %SELECTED_INDEX% LSS 0 ( set SELECTED_INDEX=0)

cls
call :ui_show_files "%FILES%" "%FILE_FILTER%" "%SELECTED_INDEX%"

choice /c QWSE /n /m " Up[W]  Down[S]  Select[E]  Quit[Q]"
if ERRORLEVEL 4 (
        REM User selected an option, so launch the viewer with the selected file
 as
        REM an argument.
        call "%VIEWER%" "%SELECTED%"
        goto :show_files
)
if ERRORLEVEL 3 ( set /a SELECTED_INDEX=!SELECTED_INDEX!+1 && goto :show_files )

if ERRORLEVEL 2 ( set /a SELECTED_INDEX=!SELECTED_INDEX!-1 && goto :show_files )

goto :eof

REM ui_show_files
REM Displays all the files in the directory given by %1, filtered by %2.  %3
REM indicates which file the user has selected.
REM
REM Returns %SELECTED%, which contains the filename of the selected file.
:ui_show_files
set COUNT=0
pushd "%~1"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir %RECURSE% /b %~2') do (
        set DISPLAY_NAME=
        if "!COUNT!"=="%~3" (
                REM This next line has a trailing space.  The space is important
.
                set DISPLAY_NAME=^>
                set SELECTED=%%a
        ) else (
                REM This next line has trailing spaces.  The spaces are importan
t.
                set DISPLAY_NAME=
        )
        set DISPLAY_NAME=!DISPLAY_NAME!%%a
        set DISPLAY_NAME=!DISPLAY_NAME:%~1=!
        echo !DISPLAY_NAME!
        set /a COUNT=!COUNT!+1
)
popd
goto :eof

REM show_splash_screen
REM Displays the splash screen on the console.
:show_splash_screen
echo.
echo. File chooser brought to you by ^>indiv^<
echo.
for %%a in (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f) do ( color 0%%a )
color
goto :eof

REM pause_sec
REM Pause for the number of seconds given by ~1.
:pause_sec
set SECS=%1
if "%SECS%"=="" ( set SECS=1)
ping 127.0.0.1 -n %SECS% >NUL
goto :eof
```

Comment: THANXS indiv!!! Can I add this to my batch? I will put your name!

Comment: Like this: Thanks for Indiv that helped me a lot!

Comment: Are you Informatic Engineer?

Comment: By posting, I donated the answer to StackOverflow, so use it however you want.  You don't have to show my name.  I only put my name in the splash screen function so you could see where to put your rocket ship.  And batch programming is just a hobby for me.

Comment: Also, I edited the answer to add the ability to search subdirectories for files to address the "file searcher" part of your question.  So if you have the script in `c:\files` and you have images in `c:\files\images` and `c:\files\more images`, it will find all the images in your subdirectories, too.

Comment: I'll put your name because I'm very grateful! Thanks for the help! Now I do not always need to click the right mouse button to open each image gif!

Comment: I really like programming, like html. But what I really want is to be a game designer! But today, I think it's very difficult to get this kind of work, because there are already many people working as a game designer.